# why is dropdown not working fine

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to give a drop down menu in my website but for some reason this drop down is not working.I am not able to figure out the reason for this.My code goes like this:

```
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">More Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">category1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">category2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">category3</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

My web page snapshot with the **li** portion marked red:
[image: my web page]

Is there any error i am doing in this stuff out there?css file being used here is bootstrap.min.css from bootstrap's official website.
EDIT:

```
<!--core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="categories.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="buysell.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```

this is my bootstrap inclusion part.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Add this JavaScript part. It's on the documentation [Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

Working fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3epa3egc/)

Comment: but it is still not working for me.i checked on fiddle t is working there but not here.

Comment: how did you add the javascript part?? Did you imported Bootstrap correctly??

Comment: yes i think so.i haven't changed the rel part of style.

Comment: Try removing other style sheets and Scripts for a while and try. Maybe something is overriding,

Comment: does bootstrap.min.css calls any other .css or .js file from within.?because i have checked every possible line in my code of adding other style and other scripts,but still getting no idea about the problem.

Comment: You have added only `bootstrap.min.css` add the `bootstrap.min.js` too. add this link. `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: no!!not working tried this also.for me everything in bootstrap.min.css is working fine,but this categories thing is not working.

Comment: What is the version of bootstrap??

Comment: Try the new version and see. V 3.3.4